# Solana-test-validator airdrop request fails

Tags: rust, solana-test-validator, airdrop

I am connected to the solana-test-validator. When I request an airdrop it fails with Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.

I have search around and have been stuck on this problem from a few days now and couldn't find a solution on the internet or any way to progress from here.

Some logs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to running solana-test-validator inside WSL fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you can always do is just adding the cluster behind your command:

```
solana airdrop 5 -ul
```

where `-ul` stands for local `-ud` for devnet and `-um` for mainnet.

Does that work?

Can you type

```
solana balance -ul
```

What does that give you?

You can also reset your local validator by running

```
solana-test-validator -r
```

maybe there is some version missmatch or smth.

Also check your solana version

```
solana --version
```

and pick stable if in doubt.

Maybe there is smth wrong with your keypair. Could you try:

```
solana-keygen grind --starts-with test:1
```

and then

```
solana airdrop -k testYourKey.json 5
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, thankyou for your reply. I have tried what you have suggested but it hasn't helped me progress unfortunately. 

Command: solana balance -ul
Gives the same error: Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.

Command: solana-test-validator -r
This just resets the validator but I still get the same errors afterwards.

Command: solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.4

Comment: Could you try with another key pair? solana-keygen grind --starts-with test:1 
 and then call solana airdrop -k testYourKey.json 5

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I was running solana-test-validator from a regular terminal on window. Switching to running solana-test-validator inside WSL fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh great to hear. Thanks for the update